# need help understanding why searchQuery.value is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-5

so i'm currently trying to build search icon on the header clickable where you're able to search for, in this case, pokemon names, however i keep getting a console error

> searchQuery.value undefined

Not sure why because the code looks valid.

Also, when you click on the search icon the icon goes above it and once you hit submit on the input it duplicates. I'm sure it's all connected the bug.

No sure why this is happening and would greatly appreciate any advice to fix this.

```js
let pokemonRepository = (function() {
  let pokemonList = [];
  // API
  let apiUrl = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=150";

  let searchIcon = $(".btn-outline-secondary");
  let modalContainer = $(".modal");
  let modalDialog = $(".modal-dialog");
  let modalContent = $(".modal-content");
  let modalBody = $(".modal-body");
  let modalTitle = $(".modal-title");
  let modalHeader = $(".modal-header");
  let modalClose = $(".btn-close");

  let listItemArray = $("li");

  function add(pokemon) {
    if (
      typeof pokemon === "object" &&
      "name" in pokemon &&
      "detailsUrl" in pokemon
    ) {
      pokemonList.push(pokemon);
    } else {
      console.error("pokemon is not correct");
    }
  }

  function getAll() {
    return pokemonList;
  }

  //  filters through pokemon names
  function search(pokemonName) {
    return pokemonList.filter((pokemon) => pokemon.name === pokemonName);
  }

  // Function adds a list of pokemon
  function addListItem(pokemon) {
    let pokemonDisplay = $(".list-group-horizontal");
    // Creates li element
    let listItem = $("<li>");
    listItem.addClass(
      "list-group-item text-center col-sm-6 col-md-4 border border-secondary bg-image img-fluid"
    );

    // Creates h1 for Pokemon Name
    let listTitle = $("<h1>");
    listTitle.html(`${pokemon.name}`);
    listTitle.addClass("display-6");

    // Creates div which holds sprites
    let listImg = $("<div>");
    loadDetails(pokemon).then(function() {
      listImg.append(
        `<img src=${pokemon.imageUrlFront} alt="${pokemon.name} sprite"/>`
      );
    });

    let listButton = $("<button>");
    listButton.text("show More");

    // Added Bootstrap Utility Class
    listButton.addClass("mp-2 btn btn-secondary");
    listButton.attr("type", "button");
    listButton.attr("data-bs-toggle", "modal");
    listButton.attr("data-bs-toggle", "#pokemonModal");

    listItem.append(listTitle);
    listItem.append(listImg);
    listItem.append(listButton);
    pokemonDisplay.append(listItem);

    buttonEvent(listButton, pokemon);
  }

  function buttonEvent(listButton, pokemon) {
    listButton.on("click", () => {
      showDetails(pokemon);
    });
  }

  function showDetails(pokemon) {
    loadDetails(pokemon).then(() => {
      // Clears existing content
      modalContainer.empty();

      modalTitle.addClass("modal-title h5 col-sml-3");

      let pokemonType = {
        fire: "text-danger",
        grass: "text-success",
        water: "text-primary",
        electric: "text-warning",
        flying: "text-info",
        poison: "text-secondary",
      };

      pokemon.types.forEach((type) =>
        modalTitle.addClass(pokemonType[type.type.name])
      );
      modalTitle.html(`${pokemon.name}`);

      modalBody.html(`
            Entry: ${pokemon.id}<br>
            Height: ${pokemon.height}<br>
            Weight: ${pokemon.weight}<br>
            Types: ${pokemon.types[0].type.name}`);

      if (pokemon.types.length === 2) {
        modalBody.innerHTML += `, ${pokemon.types[1].type.name}`;
      }

      modalBody.innerHTML += `<br>Abilities: ${pokemon.abilities[0]}.ability.name}`;

      if (pokemon.abilities.length === 2) {
        modalBody.innerHTML += `, ${pokemon.abilities[1]}.ability.name}`;
      }

      modalBody.append(`<br>
          <img src=${pokemon.imageUrlFront} alt="${pokemon.name} front sprite">
          <img src=${pokemon.imageUrlBack} alt="${pokemon.name} back sprite">
          <br>
          `);

      modalDialog.append(modalContent);
      modalContent.append(modalHeader);
      modalHeader.append(modalTitle);
      modalHeader.append(modalClose);
      modalContent.append(modalBody);
      modalContainer.append(modalDialog);
    });

    modalContainer.modal("show");
  }

  modalContainer.on("shown.bs.modal", () => {
    // Jquery eventlistener
    modalClose.on("click", () => {
      modalContainer.removeClass("fade");
      modalContainer.modal("hide");
      listItemArray[0].children().click();
    });
  });

  searchIcon.on("click", () => {
    // fetching .d-flex class in form
    let bodyHeader = $(".d-flex");
    // returns the number of child elements
    if (bodyHeader.length === 1) {
      //creates input element
      let searchQuery = $("<input>");
      searchQuery.attr("placeholder", "Pokemon Name");
      searchQuery.attr("type", "search");
      searchQuery.attr("aria-label", "search Pokemon Name");
      searchQuery.addClass("form-control my-3 ps-2 col-sm");

      searchIcon.blur();
      searchQuery.focus();
      bodyHeader.append(searchQuery);

      searchQuery.on("keydown", (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
          e.preventDefault();
          searchQuery.value =
            searchQuery.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
            searchQuery.value.slice(1);

          for (let i = 0; i < listItemArray.length; i++) {
            if (
              902 >
              listItemArray[i].children().last().getBoundingClientRect()[
                "top"
              ] &&
              listItemArray[i].children().last().getBoundingClientRect()[
                "top"
              ] > 42
            ) {
              listItemArray[i].children().last().click();
            }
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < listItemArray.length; i++) {
            if (listItemArray[i].text().split("\n")[0] === searchQuery.value) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                listItemArray[i].children().last().click();
              }, 5);
            }
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });

  // Fetches data from API
  function loadList() {
    return fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(json) {
        json.results.forEach((item) => {
          let pokemon = {
            name: item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1),
            detailsUrl: item.url,
          };
          add(pokemon);
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  function loadDetails(item) {
    let url = item.detailsUrl;
    return fetch(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(function(details) {
        item.imageUrlFront = details.sprites.front_default;
        item.imageUrlBack = details.sprites.back_default;
        item.id = details.id;
        item.height = details.height;
        item.weight = details.weight;
        item.types = details.types;
        item.abilities = details.abilities;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  return {
    add: add,
    getAll: getAll,
    addListItem: addListItem,
    search: search,
    showDetails: showDetails,
    loadList: loadList,
    loadDetails: loadDetails,
    buttonEvent: buttonEvent,
  };
})();

pokemonRepository.loadList().then(function() {
  pokemonRepository.getAll().forEach(function(pokemon) {
    pokemonRepository.addListItem(pokemon);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="The Pokédex is a simple encyclopedia of Pokémon and their characteristics." />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Pokédex App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/style.production.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg sticky-top navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a href="#home" class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="img/ball.png" width="30" height="24" alt="" class="d-inline-block align-text-top" /><span class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-secondary">Pokèdex</span>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">Home</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex row" role="search">
          <!-- <input
                  class="form-control me-2"
                  placeholder="Pokemon Name"
                  aria-label="Search"
                /> -->
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">
                  <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <p class="fw-bold position-absolute top-10 start-50 text-center text-danger"></p>
  <!-- Pokemon Display -->
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="list-group list-group-horizontal flex-fill row mt-4"></ul>
  </div>
  <!-- Display Ends Here -->

  <div class="modal fade" id="pokemonModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="pokemonModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog pt-5 text-center" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title col-sm-3" id="pokemonModalLabel"></h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close me-3" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        </div>
        <!-- Content is dynamically created using jquery -->
        <div class="modal-body"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ODmDIVzN+pFdexxHEHFBQH3/9/vQ9uori45z4JjnFsRydbmQbmL5t1tQ0culUzyK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="/src/js/scripts.js"></script>

  <script src="/src/js/promise-polyfill.js"></script>
  <script src="/src/js/fetch-pollyfill.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `searchQuery` is a jQuery object. jQuery uses `.val()`, not `.value`.

Comment: Right, thank you, I wanted to make sure. But now I'm getting on the console that "cannot assign to function call" @Barmar

Comment: You don't assign to it, you call it. `searchQuery.val(newvalue)`

Comment: ok, still a bit confused, sorry, but how would I go about calling it in this case? @Barmar

Comment: Change `searchQuery.value = something` to `searchQuery.val(something)`

Comment: hey, @Barmar, sorry to bother you but do you think you could solve me other question? here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73228820/14857998)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `searchQuery` is a jQuery object, you need to use its `.val()` method to set and get the value. So change.

```
searchQuery.value =
searchQuery.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
searchQuery.value.slice(1);
```

to

```
searchQuery.val((i, value) => value[0].toUpperCase() + value.slice(1));
```